# Return non-repeating random item from array on keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var myArray = [
    ["a", "a1", "a2", "a3"]
    //["b", "b1", "b2", "b3"],
    //["c", "c1", "c2", "c3"]
];
function getRandom(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
      return arr
  }
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
    var b = arr.splice(a, 1);
  console.log(b[0])
    return b[0];
}
function compare(entry, string) {
    for (var x in entry) {
        array1 = entry[x][0].split(' ');
        if (array1.includes(string)) {
            items = entry[x].slice(1);
            return getRandom(items)
        }
    }
}
$("#input").keydown(function(e) {
    keyword = $(this).val();
    if (e.which === 13) {
        $(this).val("");
        text = keyword.toLowerCase();
        result = '<div>' + compare(myArray, text) + '</div>'
        $('#results').append(result);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" />
<div id="results" class="reset">
```

`getRandom` function should get random item, return and remove that item, then restart the process when the original array is equal to zero but it's not working...

To test, enter `a` into input box. The result I need should be `a1, a2, and a3` one at a time in random order for the first three attempts then restart the process.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would just do a shuffle on those Arrays. If you're trying to prevent the Client from knowing about your Arrays, do it on the do it on the Server.

Comment: The array is in localStorage :)

Comment: The Client has access to their localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you pass `items` to getRandom, which is the function that alters its argument ... but `items` is created using the `slice` method, which creates a brand new array (in fact, one way to make an exact copy of an array that we can change without affecting the original is is `arr.slice()`). So the changes made by `getRandom` will not alter `myArray`.